# Understanding an outlier detection technique for fraud detection

Tags: self-study, outliers, fraud-detection

I came across this article:

http://projetoaprendizagemgrupo4.pbworks.com/f/03.03%20-%20Unsupervised%20Profiling%20Methods%20Fraud%20Detection.pdf

since I am interested in detecting abnormal behavior (in particular large values) in time series. I am interested in the approach described at page 13, "break point analysis", that up to my understanding behaves more or less like this. Apparently it is quite simple, but I lack some basic understanding I think.

We consider a time series $X(t)$ of length $N$.

Step 1 - Choose two time windows $w_1$ and $w_2$.

Step 2 - Given $t$, consider the sets $S^t_1$ and $S^t_2$ so defined:

$S^t_1=\{X(t')|t'=t-i,0 \le i \le w_1-1\}$

$S^t_2=\{X(t')|t'=t+i,1 \le i \le w_2\}$

Now consider an unpaired t-test to test the hypothesis that the mean of  $S^t_1$ is different from the mean of $S^t_2$. If the null is rejected, than the mean of $S^t_2$ is different and therefore we have an outlier in $S^t_2$.

I do not have a great understanding of hypothesis testing, but I hope to have described what is in the article.

My questions:

(1)- Let's suppose that the series does not contain any abnormal behavior and is stationary. In step 2 we will need to choose an $\alpha$ level for the test. This means that the probability of rejecting the truth in this case is $\alpha$, and therefore we will in any case detect $N\alpha$ outliers which are false positives. Is it correct ? Is this a general behavior of any test to have a substantial degree of false positives by construction ?

(2)- If (1) is true, how is this problem generally handled ? Suppose that I want to analyze a time series of length $N=1000$, and I want maximum 1 false positive. Should I choose the $\alpha$ level of the t-test low enough so that $N\alpha=1$, i.e. $\alpha=0.001$ ? Sounds quite lower than the usual $\alpha=0.05$... than the price would be an increase of type 2 errors (false negatives )?

(3)- Why do we have to choose $w_2>1$? (In the article they chose $w_1=20$ and $w_2=4$). If $w_2=1$ we would have a better understanding of where the outlier is. Some possibilities that come to my mind:

1. If $w_2=1$ the t-test works worse because the t-test assumes normality and with small sets a departure from normality if more evident.
2. If $w_2=1$ at a fixed $\alpha$ level the probability of committing a type 2 error (false negative) is higher, in other words statistical power is lower.

Is any of these the reason ?